# find out the words with substring in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of words

```
 string[] words = { "believe", "relief", "receipt", "field" };
```

How to find out the words with the substring "ei" using linq

```
IEnumerable<string> iswordlist = from word in words where words.All(a => a.Contains("ei"))
                                             select word;
            foreach (var i in iswordlist)
            {
                txtlinq.Text = txtlinq.Text + i.ToString();
            }
```

I tried the above but got no result. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
var newWord = words.Where(o => o.Contains("ei"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code won't even compile because you are using [Enumarbale.All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx) method which returns either true or false (when given condition matches) and not an IEnumerable on which you can query. You simple need a [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.100).aspx) clause.

Try this:-

```
var result = words.Where(x => x.Contains("ei"));
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:-

```
IEnumerable<string> result = from word in words
             where word.Contains("ei")
             select word;
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DaSz4W).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very good with free form, but with dot syntax this will work:

```
var ieWords = words.Where(a => a.Contains("ei"));
```